# Python changing outside dictionary from inside function

Tags: python, pointers, dictionary, copy

I am experiencing a behavior that from what I've hear is common in Python, but I'd like to know this is the default, and how to prevent this. Consider the following code:

```
dic1 = {'a':1, 'b':2}
lis1 = [1, 2]

def somefunc(dic):
    dic.update({'b':20})
    return dic

def otherfunc(lis):
    lis.append(20)
    return lis

for i in range(3):
    dic2 = dic1
    lis2 = lis1
    print(dic2)
    somefunc(dic2)
    print(lis2)
    otherfunc(lis2)
```

We I run this code, it outputs

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
[1, 2]
{'a': 1, 'b': 20}
[1, 2, 20]
{'a': 1, 'b': 20}
[1, 2, 20, 20]
```

but why doesn't it output the following?

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
[1, 2]
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
[1, 2]
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
[1, 2]
```

I feel it should output this since I am resetting `dic2` and `lis2`. Why is this the default behavior? Shouldn't Python make a copy of `dic2` once it enters the function? Shouldn't `dic2=dic1` create a copy of `dic1`, instead of creating a different pointer to the same place in memory? (if that's indeed what's happening)

I can prevent this behavior from occurring with `dic1` by replacing `dic2 = dic1` with `dic2 = dic1.copy()` (or adding `dic=dic.copy()` to the function), but how do I do it with lists? They don't have a copy method. Furthermore, is there a way for me to prevent this by default, without having to remember to use the copy method every time I deal with dictionaries (or maybe even Pandas dataframes and so on) inside a function?

Cheers

Comment: All values in Python are passed by reference. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference for a more complete explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on Python, lists are mutable, this means that lis2 is just another name for lis1, thus they are the same object

here are 2 ways to make a copy of lis1 on lis2:

```
lis2 = lis1[:]

lis2 = list(lis1)
```

I'd prefer using `list()` since it's more readable.